# adj come before noun but we dont have any endung

Tags: english-to-german, german-to-english, standard-german

> Wir haben uns gegenseitig Nachhilfe gegeben.

(Menschen B1.1 Buch)

why we cannot write (gegenseitige Nachhilfe ) the article of **Nachhilfe** is **Die** and in this sentence we must write in akk form so adj come before noun and not take endung.

regards

Answer (score 0):

Gegenseitig is in this usage not an adjective but an adverb which describes or qualifies the verb rather than the noun. For reflexive verbs the adverb usually follows the reflexive pronoun. In this case the verb is 'sich etwas geben'. In principle you could also use gegenseitig also as adjective, and then you would have to apply the ending as you describe - but doing so sounds uncommon to me. With other adverbs/adjectives both are more equally common with a minute difference in meaning, e. g. :

Das Geben ist erfolgreich (we give each other successfully help):

> wir geben uns erfolgreich Nachhilfe

Die Nachhilfe ist erfolgreich (we give each other successful help):

> wir geben uns erfolgreiche Nachhilfe

Answer (score 0):

> Wir **haben** uns gegenseitig **Nachhilfe gegeben.**

This happens because the combination *Nachhilfe geben* itself is a verb phrase in your example. Such collocations are very common in German but as the word order for them is *noun verb*, you may be fooled into thinking preceding adjectives should qualify the noun.

They don't have to. They can also qualify the verb phase as a whole, and then the adjective isn't declined.

It's especially tricky to see when the V2 rule kicks in, as then this *noun verb* word order is jumbled, and the noun ends up alone at the end, with the preceding adjective:

> Wir **geben** uns gegenseitig **Nachhilfe.**

When you have to phrase German yourself, always ask yourself whether it's really the noun that is qualified by an adjective, or rather the action.